# having trouble viewing react app on mobile device

Tags: reactjs, port, create-react-app, windows-firewall

at my wits end here. I am trying to view my react app hosted at: http://localhost:3000 on a mobile device. When I navigate to http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:3000 on my mobile device (x being my ip address) I get the error that the server refused to respond.

-I have tried adding an incoming rule in my windows defender firewall to allow access on port 3000 from tcp connections. Yet the error still persists.

-I have even temporarily attempted to turn off my firewall to test the connection and I still get the same result.

-my mobile and my localhost are on the same network

- i have specified an outgoing rule for port 3000 as well

I am using create react app for my boilerplate code so I haven't edited any of the webpack settings. I am hoping someone might have a suggestion for me as to what I can try next?

Comment: Have you tried an outgoing rule too?

Comment: Yes I have also tried setting an outgoing rule. Sorry for not specifying

Comment: Are both your mobile device and laptop connected to the same network? 
Are you trying to access it from outside the network? 
The top answer for this post might help :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device good luck!

Comment: I am connected to the same network on both devices. Thank you i'll have a look and see what I can find

Comment: @ImAnAnt this solution did help me thank you! i was using my ipv6 ip instead of my ipv4 ip address!

Comment: No worries XD 
Happy to help!
Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I used my ipv6 address instead of my ipv4 address which was the incorrect address